# Configuring Tomcat 7.0.with Eclipse Helios?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am adding the server using the server tab in the bottom

Starting from the

server tab-> Right Click on Server Tab( in the Bottom) -> New

->Server and then Selected "Tomcat v7.0 Server" .

In the new server Environment, I am using the following details

Name :- Apache Tomcat v7.0 (3)

Tomcat Installation Directory :-C:\Documents and Settings\499451\My Documents\Tomcat_7\apache-tomcat-7.0.33,,,   JRE :- jre6(installed JRE) and then I clicked on Finish Button.

Then on the Define a New Server Dialog I am using the details

Server's Host Name :- localhost

Server Name :- Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost

Server runtime Environment :- Apache Tomcat v7.0

Then I clicked on the finish button and the added tomcat server is now shown in the window under Server Tab.

But when I typed the URL : "http://localhost:8080/"

Then I am getting the following error :
HTTP Status 404 -/

type :- Status report

message :-/

description :-The requested resource is not available.
What could be the reason of this error?

Looking for Help!

Comment: Did you publish anything to the server?

Comment: No I did not. But I was trying to access the welcome page of the tomcat.

Comment: I hope you're starting the server before hitting the URL (right click on server and click start). Instead of using eclipse, first open command prompt navigate to C:\Documents and Settings\499451\My Documents\Tomcat_7\apache-tomcat-7.0.33\bin and give startup.bat command. See if the server starts-up properly. For welcome page you would need ROOT webapp in tomcat webapps folder

Comment: You will, however, want to launch it from Eclipse to actually test, and easily debug, your applications.  As mentioned, you only get a welcome page when the server's been configured to have one and serve it.

Comment: Oki,Thanks a lot Harshal Waghmare nad nitind for your replies. Now I can successfully run the web applications.